# Xamarin Forms: How to write data to a file added in the portable folder?

Tags: file, xamarin.forms

I have added a file to the portable folder of the project and set its `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`. I am trying to write data to that file using the below code:

```
string data ="123";
string fileName = "Files.STOCK.TXT";
var assembly = typeof(HomePage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{fileName}");
using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(data);
}
```

When I run I am getting the below exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Stream was not writable.
> at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean leaveOpen) [0x00035] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs:115
> at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs:88
> at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.IO.Stream)

I need to write data to the file saved in the project portable folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream from **GetManifestResourceStream** is not writable. The stream's file is embedded in the assembly at build time and cannot be changed. You need to write the file to disk before you can write to it.

```
string resource = "Files.STOCK.TXT";
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    Stream.Stream.CopyTo(stream);
    writer.Write(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I need to write data to the file saved in the portable folder. On your code where we are passing the data?

Comment: Just need to set the fs as you want

Comment: So it is not possible to write data to the file added in the portable project?

Comment: It be better to write it to external folder .

Comment: Can you check this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66850878/xamarin-forms-how-to-remove-empty-space-between-listview-items-based-on-date