# Xamarin Forms: How to remove empty space between listview items based on date?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I'm using **listview** to display the list of items. The items are getting listed based on their date. If there are multiple events in a day I need to remove the space between the events and hide the date for the items other than the first one. Now I'm hiding the date using the day visibility variable using the following code:

```
foreach (var eventshb in eventsHBList)
{
    bool isFirstItem = true;
    foreach (var events in eventshb.eventsList)
    {
        if (isFirstItem)
        {
            eventshb.dayVisibility = true;
            isFirstItem = false;
        }
        else
        {
            eventshb.dayVisibility = false;
        }
        eventshb.eventsListTO = events;
        EventAllItems.Add(eventshb);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to remove the empty space between the items. For refers, I have added the current UI and the required UI [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO4Ma.png).

The [demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t13a5cwR1mIyP1iqGAmARfp4PsSXLzju/view?usp=sharing) project using the listview for displaying the events is uploaded in the drive.

Comment: The trick you are looking for is called [grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping). And post your xaml code, maybe someone can make the gap disappear.

Comment: First you need to find out where the gap is coming from. Its almost certainly a default spacing value in some layout container (e.g. stackoverflow). Find out what property controls spacing, set it manually to zero. Does that make it go away?  Now, instead of `0`, you need a `{Binding SomeProperty}`, to have a value that you set under appropriate conditions. Read about bindings.

Comment: Could you share your sample ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Project sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t13a5cwR1mIyP1iqGAmARfp4PsSXLzju/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think use [Grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping) is the best way to achieve this,becasuse you could define a `DataTemplate` for your head.

If you don't want to make a big change you could try using `iValueConverter`,change the `Margin` value according to `dayVisibility`，but this only seems to reduce the spacing relatively.

create **IsHasSpaceConvert** :

```
public class IsHasSpaceConvert : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
              if ((bool)value)
        {
            return new Thickness(5,10,5,0);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Thickness(5,-5, 5,0);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

then in your xaml:

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:IsHasSpaceConvert x:Key="isHasSpace" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <ListView 
        x:Name="EventsListview"
        IsVisible="true"
        SeparatorVisibility="Default"
        ItemsSource="{Binding EventAllItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
        HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout 
                            Margin="{Binding dayVisibility,
                                Converter={StaticResource isHasSpace}}"
                            Padding="5"
                            Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Frame>
                                <StackLayout
                                    Orientation="Vertical">

                                    <Label 
                                        Text="{Binding finalDay}"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding dayVisibility}"
                                        TextColor="Black"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                        <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>22</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                            </OnIdiom>
                                        </Label.FontSize>
                                    </Label>

                                    <Label
                                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                        Text="{Binding eventsListTO.title}"
                                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        TextColor="Black">
                                        <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                <OnIdiom.Phone>20</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>30</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>20</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                            </OnIdiom>
                                        </Label.FontSize>
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Footer>
            <Label/>
        </ListView.Footer>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```